# Adding an ASP website in IIS7.5 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, asp-classic

I'm trying to add an ASP website under IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 and am having no luck so far. This site is just for me to hit locally. I need to make some changes to some of the HTML in some of the ASP files and I just need to be able to test my changes as I make them.

I installed IIS and checked the box for ASP. Next, I added an Application Pool which I called ASP and which has "No Managed Code" and "ASP" set. Next, I added the website by right-clicking "Sites" then clicking "Add Web Site...". I gave it a name, set it to use the ASP app pool, pointed it to the path where the ASP code is (I left it at pass-through authentication), and typed in 5555 as the port, so as to not interfere with the default website. The code is sitting on my server and the path simply uses the mapped drive that I always use to access files on that drive array.

When I type in `http://mysite:5555`, I get "`could not find mysite:5555`". I don't really know if all these settings are correct or what else I should try.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the host to "localhost" in the IIS settings for this website did the trick.

Comment: if you want to use mysite.com then you have to add a host header to that site for mysite.com.  Also you need to add a hosts file entry for mysite.com to point to your local ip.   Mysite.com 127.0.0.1.    That way you dont need to use a port other than 80 for your local etsting

Answer (score 0):

If you're having no luck, try downloading Baby ASP Web Server.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/WEB-Servers/Baby-ASP-Web-Server.shtml

As with all apps from the internet, scan for threats before installing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Firewall rules?